# PHP in between javascript

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, jwplayer

I am working on JW Player and want to add playlist dynamically with wordpress metabox. I am facing the issue to use php in between javascript

I am using JW Player and playlist code you can find here..http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/16006/javascript-playlist-in-the-jw-embedder

I am not getting any output if I use php between 'playlist':[ ...here... ] - in fact I want to use php to make it loopable so user can add multiple video to make playlist

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
                    'flashplayer': '<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ); ?>/jw/player.swf',
                    'id': 'playerID',                   
                    'width': 640,
                    'height': 540,
                    //'skin': '<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ); ?>/jw/skins/bekle/bekle.zip',  

                    <?php if ($custom_metabox->get_the_value('video_playlist') ) { ?>

                    //playlist starts
                    'playlist.position': '<?php echo $custom_metabox->get_the_value('plposition') ?>',
                    'playlist.size': '180',
                    'playlist': [

                    <?php while($custom_metabox->have_fields('playlistvideos'))
                    { ?>
                        {
                           'file': '<?php echo $custom_metabox->the_value('videourl'); ?>',
                           'title': '<?php echo $custom_metabox->the_value('videotitle'); ?>',                         
                           'image': '<?php echo $custom_metabox->the_value('videoimage'); ?>',
                           'duration': '<?php echo $custom_metabox->the_value('videoduration'); ?>',
                           'description': '<?php echo $custom_metabox->the_value('videodescription'); ?>'
                        },                      

                    <?php } ?>
                    ],  

                    <?php } ?>

                    'file': '<?php echo $custom_metabox->the_value('selfhosted'); ?>',
                    'image':'<?php echo $custom_metabox->the_value('selfhost_image'); ?>',

                });
            </script>
```

Can anyone please guide me.. here I want to use this to make clone

Comment: So what's your problem?

Comment: is the `<?php echo ..` in the string getting evaluated? I don't think you can do that?

Comment: what is your *issue* ? Please explain

Comment: What is your question?  That code looks fine.

Comment: @dm03514, what do you mean? You mean evaluated to a string?

Comment: @dm03514: PHP does not care about anything outside `<?php ... ?>`, it just outputs it literally. There is no "string" from PHP's perspective.

Comment: We cannot help you if we don't know what the problem is.

Comment: I think the trailing comma on the last result set after the last curly brace will cause a syntax issue in earlier IE versions

Comment: Ok friends thanks a lot for quick reply. I am having issue that if I am using the php for playlist (not for single) its not rendering any video but if I take it out playlist php than it works.. I have edited and added ful js code above

Comment: I am not getting any output if I use php between 'playlist':[ ...here... ] - in fact I want to use php to make it loopable so user can add multiple video to make playlist

Comment: I am using JW Player and code is this one http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/16006/javascript-playlist-in-the-jw-embedder

Comment: Hey guyz this is not fair.. I am placing code and genune question coz I dont know much about php and javascript together and post this question and you guyz don't know why giving down vote? This is not at all fair..

Comment: Where is `$custom_metabox` defined and does it have valid results?

Comment: For that I am using wpalchemy metabox script and I have placed `<?php
 // usually needed
 global $custom_metabox;
 // get the meta data for the current post
 $custom_metabox->the_meta();
   
?>` at the top of the page

Comment: You provided code, but you did not really explain the problem you are facing (only after a some time in a comment). Ask a proper question and you will get proper answers. For example, Aaron mentioned a possible issue, but we don't even know which browser you are using to test your code. It would also be useful to see the actual output of the script and see if it is valid JavaScript and whether the values are correct. So far we cannot even say if it is a PHP or JavaScript problem. Do you get any error messages? This is the information you should provide.

Comment: this issue is not any browser specific. Its happening with all browser.. anyway let me edit my question again

Comment: No I am not getting any error but as I added php in 'playlist' all metabox output just disappear from the front end. Even not only playlist related but another too.

Comment: *not getting any output* means that you get a blank page? You either have a PHP error or an infinite loop. Have you turned error reporting on? But see, that's the point. It is impossible to answer the question unless you are providing the relevant information. You should do this from the beginning, not after we ask for it.

Comment: See there are many metabox on that edit screen. and once I have placed the php everything disappear whatever getting from all metaboxes. Rest of the function like GD Star ratings. comment box, sidebar everything is there.. and there is no php error I found on frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the single quotes or replace by double quotes

```
'<?php echo $custom_metabox->the_value("selfhosted"); ?>',
```

Comment: I will try and let you know coz another issue pops up.. my all metabox now not getting any value.. let you know

Comment: I solve the issue and the issue was not related any code I have added but some variable I have reused and that was causing the issue.. thanks a lot all of you for help.